# How do I save a 2-dimensional array as a csv file?

Tags: vb.net, csv

I am using visual studio 8. vb.net.
I have an array, array1(100,8) and I want to save it as a csv file so that I can open it in
excel and examine the contents more closely. The feature, of saving as a csv file, is not going to form an integral part of the finished vb app, I just need something quick and dirty because the data in the array just requires looking at in excel so that I can fully understand its significance and thus continue coding my app.

Thank you for all and any help you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested C#:

```
    static void WriteCsv<T>(T[,] data, string path)
    {
        char[] specialChars = {',','\"', '\n','\r'};
        using (var file = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            int height = data.GetLength(0), width = data.GetLength(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0) file.WriteLine();
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    string value = Convert.ToString(data[i, j]);
                    if (value.IndexOfAny(specialChars) >= 0)
                    {
                        value = "\"" + value.Replace("\"", "\"\"")
                            + "\"";
                    }
                    if (j > 0) file.Write(',');
                    file.Write(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Which reflector translates as:

```
Private Shared Sub WriteCsv(Of T)(ByVal data As T(0 To .,0 To .), ByVal path As String)
    Dim specialChars As Char() = New Char() { ","c, """"c, ChrW(10), ChrW(13) }
    Using file As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(path)
        Dim height As Integer = data.GetLength(0)
        Dim width As Integer = data.GetLength(1)
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To height - 1
            If (i > 0) Then
                file.WriteLine
            End If
            Dim j As Integer
            For j = 0 To width - 1
                Dim value As String = Convert.ToString(data(i, j))
                If (value.IndexOfAny(specialChars) >= 0) Then
                    value = ("""" & value.Replace("""", """""") & """")
                End If
                If (j > 0) Then
                    file.Write(","c)
                End If
                file.Write(value)
            Next j
        Next i
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Marc you are fantastic! Thank you so much for taking the time and trouble to do all that. I had to copy and paste the original c into another translator, developerfusion, because the reflector code produced errors - but hang that small inconvenience, I really am very very grateful.  And once again, ty to all who took the time to offer help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a vb compiler on me, but maybe this pseudocode will help

```
textStream = File.OpenText("c:\output.csv")
for i = 0 to 99
{
  for j = 0 to 7
  {
    write array1[i][j] to textStream
    write "," to textStream
  }
  write newline to textStream
}
close textstream
```

Next, open the file in excel.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. Yup I do need to export from vb.net not import. So far I have 

FileOpen(1, "d:\webfile.txt", OpenMode.Binary)
        For i = 0 To 99
            For k = 0 To 7
                FilePutObject(1, array1(i, k))
            Next k
        Next i
And this saves it as a text file, but what I need is a csv file that excel can open. Using this method but saving as a .csv file results in a file that excel does not recognise. Ummm what to do?

Comment: Use ';' instead of commas to make Excel auto-recognize it. That alone won't help for fields containing the semicolon (quoting may help in that case) and for different character sets (Excel defaults to the ANSI character set specified in Windows). Also, this won't work on Excel for Mac.

Comment: @fantails don't save as webfile.txt, save as webfile.csv