# Create CSV from array in VBA

Tags: vba, csv, outlook

I'm a novice programmer trying to automate some repetitive workplace tasks that should be done by a clever script instead of humans. I've done some VBA and Java, but very basic stuff.

We have some data generated by a validated online form that gets emailed to a mailbox, and then a filter in the mail client (Outlook 2010) puts it into a particular folder. My intention is to write some VBA that when triggered will check the contents of that folder, and then for each mail item, get the message body text as a string, create an array, and then write the array contents into a .csv file. I'll then have another app (iMacros for Firefox) read the csv and interact with an in-house corporate webapp to do the rest.

I think I can do all of that except write the array contents to csv.

I work best from looking at code examples (I do try to understand the MS Object Model documentation), but the best I can find for writing a VBA array to CSV is something like:

```
  'save the file
  Open sFileName For Output As #7
  For n = 0 To UBound(MyArray, 1)
    Print #7, Format(MyArray(n, 0), "0.000000E+00")
  Next n
  Close #7
```

I think this is VB and not VBA, but is the general idea here valid? Or if anyone else has a code sample to get me started or any other pointers I'd be very grateful.

PS Have also seen [How do I save a 2-dimensional array as a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353325/how-do-i-save-a-2-dimensional-array-as-a-csv-file) but can't understand it.

Answer (score 2):

The code below works for converting 2D arrays in CSV. I have not written the code, but have tested it and it works!

```
' SaveAsCSV saves an array as csv file. Choosing a delimiter different as a comma, is optional.
'
' Syntax:
' SaveAsCSV dMyArray, sMyFileName, [sMyDelimiter]
'
' Examples:
' SaveAsCSV dChrom, app.path & "\Demo.csv"       --> comma as delimiter
' SaveAsCSV dChrom, app.path & "\Demo.csv", ";"  --> semicolon as delimiter
'
' Rev. 1.00 [8 jan 2003]
' written by P. Wester
' wester@kpd.nl


Public Sub SaveAsCSV(MyArray() As Variant, sFilename As String, Optional sDelimiter As String = ",")

Dim n As Long 'counter
Dim M As Long 'counter
Dim sCSV As String 'csv string to print

On Error GoTo ErrHandler_SaveAsCSV


'check extension and correct if needed
If InStr(sFilename, ".csv") = 0 Then
  sFilename = sFilename & ".csv"
Else
  While (Len(sFilename) - InStr(sFilename, ".csv")) > 3
    sFilename = Left(sFilename, Len(sFilename) - 1)
  Wend
End If

'If MultiDimensional(MyArray()) = False Then '1 dimension

  'save the file
'  Open sFileName For Output As #7
'  For n = 0 To UBound(MyArray(), 1)
'    Print #7, Format(MyArray(n, 0), "0.000000E+00")
'  Next n
'  Close #7

'Else 'more dimensional

  'save the file
  Open sFilename For Output As #7
  For n = 1 To UBound(MyArray(), 1)
    sCSV = ""
    For M = 1 To UBound(MyArray(), 2)
      sCSV = sCSV & Format(MyArray(n, M)) & sDelimiter
    Next M
    sCSV = Left(sCSV, Len(sCSV) - 1) 'remove last Delimiter
    Print #7, sCSV
  Next n
  Close #7

'End If

Exit Sub


ErrHandler_SaveAsCSV:
  Close #7
```

Comment: Works great, just have to add this in case there are commas in the field record.

 `code`Dim RecordAt As String

and 

    For m = LBound(MyArray(), 2) To UBound(MyArray(), 2)
       RecordAt = Format(MyArray(n, m))
       If InStr(RecordAt, ",") > 0 Then RecordAt = Chr(34) & RecordAt & Chr(34)
      
      sCSV = sCSV & RecordAt & sDelimiter
    Next m  `code`

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with VB so I'm not sure about the open file for output #7 but if that works (test it with some random output), then your code snippet is right. The only thing is that you should have another Print call where you add a ",".

Just make sure that on your last iteration you don't add the ",". You can do this by adding an If statement that will check if n = UBound(MyArray) - 1 (Which is the index of the last element.)

Hope it helps,

PM

Answer (score 0):

This is an excel based solution. If you control outlook from excel this could be a viable solution. Additionally if you are working on an excel project this could be of use.

```
Private Sub ArrayToCsvWorkborkMethod(MyArray As Variant, FileName As String)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Add
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = WB.Sheets(1)

Dim Target As Range
Set Target = Range("A1").Resize(UBound(MyArray, 1), UBound(MyArray, 2))
Target.Value = MyArray
WB.SaveAs FileName, 23
WB.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I solved it this way instead. This is slower but eliminates any weird formatting the previous solution might do.
This creates a new workbook, Writes your array to the worksheet, saves that new workbook as a CSV file and than closes the new workbook.

At least for me this works much more reliably and offloads any formatting concerns to excel.