# VBA - 2D Array to CSV

Tags: arrays, export-to-csv

I have the following Sub below (which i got form somewhere), which is supposed to creates a csv from a 2D array.  it kind o, sort works but there are issues that i am not sure how to resolve.  as you can see from the image, notepad is shows unprintable characters in the file.  Which i cannot seem to find in the code or remove.

any assistance is greatly appreciate, thank you in advance.

```
Public Sub SaveCSV(arr_SelectedCMHist() As Variant, path As String, Optional Delim As String = ",", Optional quote As String = """")

    Dim opf As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim column As Long
     
        If Dir(path) <> "" Then Kill path
     
        opf = FreeFile
        Open path For Binary As #opf
     
        For row = LBound(arr_SelectedCMHist, 1) To UBound(arr_SelectedCMHist, 1)
            For column = LBound(arr_SelectedCMHist, 2) To UBound(arr_SelectedCMHist, 2)
                Put #opf, , quote & arr_SelectedCMHist(row, column) & quote
                If column < UBound(arr_SelectedCMHist, 2) Then Put #opf, , Delim
            Next column
            If row < UBound(arr_SelectedCMHist, 1) Then Put #opf, , vbCrLf
        Next row
        
        Close #opf
 
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is another version using the [`FileSystemObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) and `Strings.Join()`

```
Public Sub SaveAsCSV(ByRef data() As Variant, ByVal sFilename As String, Optional ByVal sDelimiter As String = ",", Optional ByVal quote As String = """")
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fs As TextStream
    Set fs = fso.OpenTextFile(sFilename, ForWriting, True)
    
    Dim n_rows As Long, n_cols As Long
    n_rows = UBound(data, 1)
    n_cols = UBound(data, 2)
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim temp() As String
    ReDim temp(1 To n_cols)
    For i = 1 To n_rows
        For j = 1 To n_cols
            If IsNumeric(data(i, j)) Then
                temp(j) = CStr(data(i, j))
            Else
                temp(j) = quote & data(i, j) & quote
            End If
        Next j
        
        fs.WriteLine Strings.Join(temp, sDelimiter)
    Next i
    fs.Close

End Sub
```

A [TextStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/textstream-object) is a more modern approach to file manipulations.

The single line of code that writes the data is `fs.WriteLine Strings.Join(temp, sDelimiter)` and the remaining code is just data manipulation to add " to non-numeric values. The `Join()` command takes an array of strings and combines the elements into a single string with a delimiter. `["a","b","c"] => "a,b,c"` so you don't have to manually decide when to write the delimiter and when not.

A sample driving code for the above is (defined under a worksheet)

```
Public Sub T()

    Dim x() As Variant
    x = Range("C4").Resize(22, 4).Value2
    Call SaveAsCSV(x, "test_data.csv")

End Sub
```

with results

[image: ex]

---

<sub>Remember to add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` in order to have access to the `FileSytemObject` class</sub>

[image: scr]

Answer (score 0):

I went via another approach, I hope this helps someone in the future, which i got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191560/create-csv-from-array-in-vba/10313737#10313737)

```
Public Sub SaveAsCSV(arr_SelectedCMHist() As Variant, sFilename As String, Optional sDelimiter As String = ",", Optional quote As String = """")

Dim n As Long 'counter
Dim M As Long 'counter
Dim sCSV As String 'csv string to print

opf = FreeFile

  Open sFilename For Output As #opf
  For n = 0 To UBound(arr_SelectedCMHist(), 1)
    sCSV = ""
    For M = 0 To UBound(arr_SelectedCMHist(), 2)
      sCSV = sCSV & quote & Format(arr_SelectedCMHist(n, M)) & quote & sDelimiter
    Next M
    sCSV = Left(sCSV, Len(sCSV) - 1) 'remove last Delimiter
    Print #opf, sCSV
  Next n
  Close #opf

End Sub
```