# Can you directly write the contents of an array in excel VBA to a CSV file?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, csv

I have some code which loads a table into an array, does some calculations, creates a new sheet, writes the changed array to the new sheet, and saves that new sheet as a CSV.

I need a CSV because that is the only format the destination system this is for accepts.

I was wondering if it is possible to directly write the array to a CSV skipping 2 steps.

Through my research I found the below code from [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191560/create-csv-from-array-in-vba) however i cannot get it to work.

```
' SaveAsCSV saves an array as csv file. Choosing a delimiter different as a comma, is optional.
'
' Syntax:
' SaveAsCSV dMyArray, sMyFileName, [sMyDelimiter]
'
' Examples:
' SaveAsCSV dChrom, app.path & "\Demo.csv"       --> comma as delimiter
' SaveAsCSV dChrom, app.path & "\Demo.csv", ";"  --> semicolon as delimiter
'
' Rev. 1.00 [8 jan 2003]
' written by P. Wester
' wester@kpd.nl


Public Sub SaveAsCSV(MyArray() As Variant, sFilename As String, Optional sDelimiter As String = ",")

Dim n As Long 'counter
Dim M As Long 'counter
Dim sCSV As String 'csv string to print

On Error GoTo ErrHandler_SaveAsCSV


'check extension and correct if needed
If InStr(sFilename, ".csv") = 0 Then
  sFilename = sFilename & ".csv"
Else
  While (Len(sFilename) - InStr(sFilename, ".csv")) > 3
    sFilename = Left(sFilename, Len(sFilename) - 1)
  Wend
End If

'If MultiDimensional(MyArray()) = False Then '1 dimension

  'save the file
'  Open sFileName For Output As #7
'  For n = 0 To UBound(MyArray(), 1)
'    Print #7, Format(MyArray(n, 0), "0.000000E+00")
'  Next n
'  Close #7

'Else 'more dimensional

  'save the file
  Open sFilename For Output As #7
  For n = 1 To UBound(MyArray(), 1)
    sCSV = ""
    For M = 1 To UBound(MyArray(), 2)
      sCSV = sCSV & Format(MyArray(n, M)) & sDelimiter
    Next M
    sCSV = Left(sCSV, Len(sCSV) - 1) 'remove last Delimiter
    Print #7, sCSV
  Next n
  Close #7

'End If

Exit Sub


ErrHandler_SaveAsCSV:
  Close #7
```

Using this syntax

```
    SaveAsCSV arOut, Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Demo.csv"
```

I get this error on that line. Type Mismatch: array or user defined type expected.
I can remedy this by editing this line and removing the parenthesis.

```
Public Sub SaveAsCSV(MyArray() As Variant, sFilename As String, Optional sDelimiter As String = ",")
```

Changed to

```
Public Sub SaveAsCSV(MyArray As Variant, sFilename As String, Optional sDelimiter As String = ",")
```

However this only creates a blank file as there is now an error here. This triggers the error handling.
[image: Image of error]

What I cant figure out is when I watch MyArray in the watch window it is populated the way it is supposed to be so I cannot figure out this error. Any help is appreciated

Comment: remove the `()`

Comment: @ScottCraner That appears to have worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between a `Variant` and an `Array of Variant`
A `Variant` variable in VBA can hold *anything*, and that includes an array. An Array is always an Array:

```
Dim v1 as Variant
v1 = 3                   ' Now v1 holds an Integer
Redim v1(1 to 10)        ' ...and now it holds an array of Variant
v1(1) = 3                ' The first member of v1 now holds an Integer 
v1 = "VBA is a miracle"  ' Now v1 holds a string (and is no longer an array)

Dim v2() as Variant      ' v2 is an array of Variant per declaration
Redim v2(1 to 10)        ' Assign 10 members to v2
v2(1) = 3                ' The first member of v1 now holds an Integer 
v2 = "VBA is a mystery"  ' This is not possible as v2 is an array!
                         ' (Compiler error "Can't assign to an array)
```

If you declare your Sub with parameter `MyArray() As Variant`, you are saying that your function expects an *Array of* Variants as parameter. In your call `SaveAsCSV arOut, Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Demo.csv"`, you are passing the variable `arOut` as argument.
This variable is most likely declared as `Variant` (not as *Array of* Variant), and therefore you get the first compiler error: A variant is not an Array of Variant. The compiler simply cannot know that during runtime, `arOut` will be an array. It could also be an Integer or String or anything else.

Now you changed the parameter of your routine declaration to `MyArray As Variant` and your call gets valid, the compiler no longer complains, it assumes that `MyArray` can be anything. If you assign a number or string to it, the Sub will be called anyhow (of course it will not work).

Within the routine, you write `UBound(MyArray(), 1)`. The compiler again complains because `MyArray` is *not* an Array. By changing the call to `UBound(MyArray, 1)`, the compiler is happy. If `MyArray` doesn't hold an array, you will get a Runtime error (Type mismatch).

So using `MyArray as Variant` in the function declaration and removing the parenthesis when using it in `UBound` solves your issue, everybody is happy.

*With a little drawback*: As already mentioned, the compiler cannot protect you from calling the Sub with an invalid argument. As a programmer, you want the compiler to catch as many problems as possible. So an alternative would be to declare `arOut` as Array:

```
Dim arOut() as Variant
arOut = Range("A1:F10")  ' Do whatever magic you need to fill the array.
```

Now you can go back to the declaration `Public Sub SaveAsCSV(MyArray() As Variant...`. And using `UBound(myArray(), 1)` will work, too. However, you can (and should) write `UBound(myArray, 1)` in any case.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I wasn't aware you could create a variable that could only be an array. I thought using plain old variants was the only way. Can you explain this line. "However, you can (and should) write UBound(myArray, 1) in any case." Wouldn't I want to use Ubound(myArray(), 1)" that way if i feed it something that isn't an array it throws an error?

arOut should and will only be an array.

Comment: As `myArray` is already declared as array, there is no risk that a "Type mismatch" runtime error happens and the extra-parenthesis just let the statement look more complicated (to be honest, I just learned from your code and experimenting that it's valid syntax, never saw this before).

Comment: And of course in any case you have the risk of a runtime error "Array out bounds" when you pass a 1-dimensional array as argument and uses `UBound(MyArray, 2)`